# How to find all available 'packages' in .NET 6.0 SDK on Windows

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, .net-core, cmd

Due to security reasons, I need to be able to verify all the packages included in the .NET 6.0.405 SDK.

I've installed the SDK, and attempted to use `dotnet list package` command, but this only works when specifying a project/solution. I don't want to make a project, I just want to be able to view all the packages POSSIBLE to use in a project with the base install of .NET SDK.

For example, I need a list of packages such as:

```
...
System.Collections.Immutable
System.Collections.Specialized
System.ComponentModel.Annotations
...
```

There should be many more, from NETCore, AspNetCore, WindowsDesktop, etc.

Is there a way to find this information through the CLI on Windows, or somewhere listed in the documentation I can't find?

Comment: _"Due to security reasons, I need to be able to verify all the packages included in the .NET 6.0.405 SDK."_ - I think you misunderstand how the .NET SDK works... (also, **what** "security reasons", exactly? Which _specific_ information-security standard are you being instructed to follow?)

Comment: What do you need to verify about the packages?

Comment: @Dai I need to verify which packages exist, on a base install. I just need to know what individual .dll / packages are in the install prior to me installing it. 

I know the SDK includes .NET Runtime 6.0.13, ASP.NET Core Runtime 6.0.13, .NET Desktop Runtime 6.0.13, but I need to know all the individual components that comprise all of these.

Comment: @SignalProcessed There is no "base install" of the .NET SDK - it's specific to every system. Also, the SDK gets updated every couple of weeks so I think you're wasting your time, honestly. And you still haven't told us the _actual business reason_ for you doing this. (If you're concerned about supply-chain-attacks on build infrastructure then you should ask about _that_ instead, instead of specifically about the .NET SDK.

Comment: You showed your emotions with the words like "I need" and "I just want", but those can prevent you from thinking thoroughly on how to identify the information you actually wanted. A few years ago when [I faced a similar challenge](https://halfblood.pro/offline-publishing-asp-net-core-apps-cf22f45158af) I was able to build a clean virtual machine and use tools like Process Monitor to analyze the behavior of `dotnet` CLI so as to learn where the NuGet packages are and how they might be used. However, .NET 6/7 changed so much so you have to start from scratch. Be patient and good luck.

Comment: @Dai Of course, the questioner should make the goals clearer, as there might be other options. But I think there is nothing wrong to ask a specific question about .NET SDK related supply-chain-attacks.

Comment: @Dai By base install I mean, the install that occurs when you run the latest downloaded .exe of the .NET SDK x64 Windows version. There are no options during the install, it simply installs the libraries. I suppose I'm probably misunderstanding something?

I have to do this to provide a cybersecurity rep a list of all these libraries before I can install. I don't know why this is done, but it is a requirement that is immovable.

Comment: @SignalProcessed _"I have to do this to provide a cybersecurity rep a list of all these libraries before I can instal"_ - either (or both) of you are embarking on a fool's errand. For a start: it sounds like you're being asked to audit Microsoft's shipping code - which is of no value - secondly: assemblies in the .NET BCL are not "packages" (I suspect people might be using words from Java-land in .NET where they have very different meanings...) - and there is absolutely no requirement to ever use NuGet with .NET: using libraries via the old-fashioned _Add Reference..._ approach is still valid.